# How to setup mod_rewrite with fallbacks if target URL doesn't exist?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I setup mod_rewrite in such a way that if the target URL doesn't exist, it can check the next rule, and then the next, until it finds an existing URL?

My situation is that I have a set of image files on a remote CDN. I'm using mod_rewrite to obscure the actual URL of those images by rewriting like this (*terribly simplified example*):

```
THIS:    http://mydomain.com/123456789/image.jpg?num=1
TO THIS: http://123456789.remoteserver.com/image1.jpg

THIS:    http://mydomain.com/123456789/image.jpg?num=3
TO THIS: http://123456789.remoteserver.com/image3.jpg
```

Here's a simplified example of my current mod_rewrite to help visualize:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^num=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/image.jpg$ http://$1.remoteserver.com/image%1.jpg [P]
```

It works **perfectly** as is, but I need to complicate things a little so that if "image1.jpg" doesn't exist, it can check for "image2.jpg," and if that doesn't exist, it can check for "image3.jpg," etc. - up to 5 or 6 different images - and rewrite to the first existing URL it finds. Is this even possible?

Comment: Have a look here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s

Comment: thanks @PanamaJack, but i think that only applies to local files - not remote. am i mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It works perfectly as is, but I need to complicate things a little so that if "image1.jpg" doesn't exist, it can check for "image2.jpg," and if that doesn't exist, it can check for "image3.jpg," etc. - up to 5 or 6 different images - and rewrite to the first existing URL it finds. Is this even possible?

Not with mod_rewrite. When it gets to the `[P]` flag and ends its rewriting, the URL processing pipeline moves on, and mod_rewrite *will never know how that request resolved*. In other words, it'll never know if `image1.jpg` exists, if there was an error, if the request timed out, etc.

You'll have to probably employ a script or something to do this. For example, if you change your rules to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^num=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/image.jpg$ /proxy_image.php?path=$1&num=%1 [L]
```

Then in the `proxy_image.php` script, have something like:

```
$num = $_GET['num'];
$success = false;
while($success == false) {
    $image = "image" . $num . ".jpg";
    $url = "http://" . $_GET['path'] . ".remoteserver.com/" . $image;
    $contents = loadImageUrl($url);
    if($contents === 0) {
        $success = false;
        $num++;
    }
    else {
        returnToBrowser($contents);
        break;
    }
}
```

You'll have to write the pseudo functions in the code, but you get the idea.

Comment: i was afraid of that! thanks @JonLin. i was hoping to avoid a proxy because of its probable impact on speed/performance, but your explanation that mod_rewrite "will never know" makes sense.